# fixing a basic prenex form conversion (most of it is done)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

i am trying to fix a conversion to basic prenex i've been doing for a while with no success. would appreciate understanding what i'm doing wrong:

$((∃x∀yp(x) \land (∃x∀y(s(y) \to  q(y,x))) \lor ∃x∃yR(x,y))$

so first we'll rename the variables and change $s(y)) \to  q(y,x) \equiv \lnot s(y) \lor q(y,x)$

so we get:

$\equiv ((∃a∀bp(a) \land (∃c∀d(\lnot s(d) \lor  q(d,c))) \lor ∃x∃yR(x,y))$

now we'll take x,y out:

$\equiv \exists y \exists x(∃a∀bp(a) \land (∃c∀d(\lnot s(d) \lor  q(d,c))) \lor R(x,y))$

now c,d:

$\equiv \exists y \exists x \exists c \forall d(∃a∀bp(a) \land (\lnot s(d) \lor  q(d,c)) \lor R(x,y))$

we'll take a,b out:

$\equiv \exists y \exists x \exists c \exists a \forall d \forall b(p(a) \land (\lnot s(d) \lor  q(d,c)) \lor R(x,y))$.

my main problem for here is continuing with $\lnot$, as i'm not sure how to proceed.

thank you very much for helping me and correcting me if i've done any mistake along the way!

Comment: Just use implication equivalence again.  (There was really no need to use it in the first place, as the implication was contained within the scope of the quantifiers and did not contain any quantifiers within its antecedant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$((∃x∀y~p(x) \land (∃x∀y~(s(y) \to  q(y,x))) ~\lor~ ∃x∃y~R(x,y))$$

Since there are no quantification within that implication, it can be treated as a single predicate, so we may temporarily substitute: $T(y,x)\equiv (s(y)\to q(y,x))$.

$$\big((\exists x\forall y~p(x))\land (\exists x\forall y~T(y,x))\big)\lor (\exists x\exists y~R(x,y))$$

Then (with assurance that $a,b,c,d$ do not occur freely within $p(x),T(y,x),$ or $R(x,y)$) alpha-substitution gives:

$$\big((\exists a\forall b~p(a))\land (\exists c\forall d~T(d,c))\big)\lor (\exists x\exists y~R(x,y))$$

And so distribution of quantifiers then gives:

$$\exists a\forall b~\exists c\forall d~\exists x\exists y~\Big(\big(p(a)\land T(d,c)\big)\lor R(x,y)\Big)$$

Note: the order of the three *pairs* of quantifiers is not critical, although the order *within* the first two is.

Then it is just a matter of releasing the temporary substitution: $T(d,c)\equiv (s(d)\to q(d,c))$

$$\exists a\forall b~\exists c\forall d~\exists x\exists y~\Big(\big(p(a)\land (s(d)\to q(d,c))\big)\lor R(x,y)\Big)$$

---

If you wish, you *may* distribute the existentials forward.

$$\exists x\exists y\exists a\exists c~\forall b\forall d~\Big(\big(p(a)\land (s(d)\to q(d,c))\big)\lor R(x,y)\Big)$$

---

Remark: That $\forall b$ seems a bit redundant...

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot in spotting and correcting my mistakes